# How to dynamically add filter to IMongoCollection in C# and MongoDB version="2.2.3"?

Tags: c#, mongodb

This is my code:

```
var database = new MongoClient("mongodb://192.168.3.122").GetDatabase("xxxx");   
var collection = database.GetCollection<School>("School");

//var it = new List<IMongoQuery>();
//it.Add(Query.EQ("Phone", "77915656"));
//it.Add(Query.EQ("EstablishedYear", 1349));

//var query = new QueryBuilder<School>();
//query.And(it);

IMongoQuery query = new QueryDocument();

Query.And(query, Query.EQ("Phone", "77915656"));
Query.And(query, Query.EQ("EstablishedYear", 1349));
collection.Find(query).ToList(); // eror here!!!
```

I don't know how to get result from query?!

And error is:

> 'MongoDB.Driver.IMongoCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Find' and the best extension method overload 'MongoDB.Driver.IMongoCollectionExtensions.Find(MongoDB.Driver.IMongo‌​Collection, MongoDB.Driver.FilterDefinition, MongoDB.Driver.FindOptions)' has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `QueryDocument` does not contain the type, which `Find` requires... if you want to create a filter, use a filter builder... out of my mind:

```cs
var database = new MongoClient("mongodb://192.168.3.122").GetDatabase("xxxx");   
var collection = database.GetCollection<School>("School");

var builder = Builders<School>.Filter;
var filter = builder.Eq("Phone", "77915656");
filter = filter & builder.Eq("EstablishedYear", 1349);

var myFilteredList = collection.Find(filter).ToList();
```